# using req.params vs req.query in Next.js dynamic api routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

I am trying to access params in my Next.js API routes. I am just wondering why in order to access a certain dynamic route `id` I must use `req.query` when normally in express I would access the `id` via `params`. Is `req.query` the correct way of accessing the `id`?

I have the following api folder structure.

```
/pages
  /api
    /posts
      -index.js
      -[postId].js
```

In my `[postId]` file I have the following

```
function handler(req, res) {
  // shows undefined
  console.log(req.params);
  const postId = req.params.postId;
```

and my api call is as follows:

```
fetch(`/api/posts/${id}`)
```

Comment: The docs say that to access the id, you need to use `req.query`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to [nextJs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes), all examples uses `req.query` to get the id or other parameters:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  return <p>Post: {pid}</p>
}

export default Post
```

So there's nothing wrong with this approach.

Nextjs doesn't explicit says why they use `query` instead of `params`, but in the section about [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) you can get some clues:

> the route /post/abc?foo=bar will have the following query object:

```
{ "foo": "bar", "pid": "abc" }
```

Probably they use query as a way to join both params and query in one object or it's just more convenient to use that way, so as there's no reference about it you don't have to care that much, just use the query and be happy.

Comment: What if I have API structure like /posts/:post_id/create OR /posts/:post_id/update then 
  /api
    /posts
      /[post_id]
        -create.js
        -update.js 

I am trying to do something like this, but not able to get req.params.post_id
Please correct me if I am following wrong approach. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to get it from req.query? Take a look at [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes)

Comment: Yes @Yago I tried with req.query and it worked perfectly. :)